# Icon for content Page in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, icons

I am trying to get page icons work. I created a blank application and added a icon to it. when I run the app the icon does not render.
What am I missing. This seems like it should be straight forward.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
         prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
         x:Class="Sandbox.Views.MainPage"
         Title="MainPage" Icon="icon.png">
   <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
        <Label Text="{Binding Title}" />
   </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

Comment: check if the image is added into the android resource folder or not.

Comment: when I created the project, there is a icon.png by default. I am using the same image

Comment: remove the .png from the icon and try

Comment: You mean from the XAML here?   Icon="icon.png">

Comment: yes from the XAML

Comment: Removed it. No icon/image on the screen ....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144097/discussion-between-shabir-jan-and-katie77).

Answer (score 2):

In your MainPage code-behind file (**MainPage.xaml.cs**), try using the SetTitleIcon method of the NavigationPage (assuming you're using a navigation page).

```
public MainPage() 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon(this, "icon.png");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Android, that Icon should be set in MainActivity like [Icon = "@drawable/icon"].

But I think you can try another way, to do whatever you want in Navigation bar
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92502/easier-way-to-create-popup-view-and-custom-navigation-bar#latest